# Does Extend function return a new list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm using `extend` function to add new item in a list. And gives me `None` in output.

```
 p=["a",1,"b",2,"c",3]
 a=p.extend(["d",4])
 print(a)
```

Output `None`

Why It is giving none instead of ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4]

Comment: please check [ask] - you should at least specify what you wanted to do, what have you tried, what is going wrong and what is the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because using `extend` function, you just extend it but not make any new list. So nothing is assigned it variable `a`. You should do following:

```
p=["a",1,"b",3,"c",4]
p.extend(["qeq",14])
print(p)
```

This method does not return any value but add the content to existing list. [Check this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm) for more.